# How to get a list of categories by product number?

Tags: magento

I need to sort categoies by product number that means which category has large number of products is shown at the top of category list. So catgories list should be descending order by product number.
any help would be appreciated!

I have categories and its product as following as:

```
category                           no of products

cell phones                                 5
cameras                                     8
computers                                   3
```

I would like to sort categories **cameras,cell phones,computers** by product number .For this sorting result i would like to use join in **collection class of category**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will fetch the product per category:-

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                         ->addCategoryFilter($category);

$productCount = $productCollection->count();
```

You can do in this way:-

- Get an array of all categories
- Loop through them
- Fetch product collection with product count for each category (*from the above code*).
- Sort categories with the product count.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a collection of categories called `$collection` then you can do this:

```
$collection->setOrder('children_count', 'desc');
```

**Edit:**
To make it the default in an overridden collection use this method:

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->setOrder('children_count', 'desc');
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I am overriding collection class of category and i want to sort categories by product number so i need to change in collection.Any Idea to sort all categories in default magento by product number.